# Share bloc across multiple routes and not throughout my whole app

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc

How do you keep the same instance of one bloc (the same state essentially) across multiple screens, without building it for the whole app ?

For example if your registering part of your app is in multiple screens. But when i exit those screens the bloc should be disposed of.

I thought about using nested routes while using provider package to instantiate the bloc to child pages (while using the context of the parent page), is that the right way to do it ?

Comment: For `provider`, this would require https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/33213. If you want it, like a +1 or a comment

Comment: Really interesting ! How will you go about implementing this with for example flutter_bloc by Felix Angelov  ? Will you be able to implement something in Provider itself ?

Comment: It'd be in provider itself. Then flutter_bloc, which depends on it, will be able to use it

Comment: Great to hear ! Let's hope for an agreement from their part to change the framework :/